# Color complexes

Tags: colour-complex

Regarding weak color complexes and attacks on them, the games [Szabo-Geller](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1136788) and [Geller-Najdorf](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1048646) from the [1953 Candidates Tournament in Zurich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zurich_1953_chess_tournament) come to my mind, as well the more recent [Grischuk-Gelfand](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1573209) from the [2010 Linares tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linares_International_Chess_Tournament#2010). Of course, there are many others.

Yet I don't know of a [chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess) [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_strategy) or positional book with at least one section dedicated to color complexes (how to make them weak, how to exploit the weakness).

I would be glad to have references, if they exist.

Comment: Why remove the link to the Linares Tournament wiki?  Future visitors or those new to chess may be unfamiliar with the tournament.

Comment: If they are unfamiliar with Linares tournament (or with Zurich 53' for which there is also a wiki entry mind you), they can choose their favourite web browser, use their favourite chess engine and look for those tournaments. Results will pop up immediately. But besides that, it is not mandatory to put the link, hence I wanted my initial question to remains as I wrote it. :)

Comment: Sounds good. I was just curious. I agree "*it is not mandatory...*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Here are two  books that explicitly have material focused on this concept.

**Seirawan & Silman (2020)** have a subsection dedicated to "Color Control." Games analyzed include

- Damjanovic – Fischer (1970)
- Seirawan – Short (1982)

**Weeramantry & Euseibi (2020)** include an entire section of the book for "Weak Squares." The opening paragraph states

> "The games in this section...illustrate how exploiting weak squares,
> whether on one or both colors, allows a player to infiltrate the
> opponent's position and develop a successful attack."

Annotated games include:

- Alekhine – Yates (1922)
- Lamon – Weeramantry (1990)
- Harris – Weeramantry (1972)
- Tarrasch – Reti (1922)
- Alekhine – Yates (1923)
- Short – Timman (1991)
- Dobias – Podgorny (1952)
- Karpov – Shirov (1992)
- Taimanov – Najdorf (1953)
- R. Byrne – Fischer (1963)
- Fischer – Myagmarsuren (1967)
- Gelfand – Andreikin (2014)
- Weeramantry – Kumar (2004)
- Kramnik – Van Wely (2008)
- Graif – Ali Maranda (2019)

---

[image: image showing both book covers]

**References:**

Seirawan, Yasser; Silman, Jeremy. 2020. *Winning Chess Strategies*, Everyman Chess, Blue Ridge Summit, PA. See pp. 101–107.

Weeramantry, Sunil; Eusebi, Edward. 2020. *Best Lessons of a Chess Coach: Extended Edition*, Mongoose Press, Boston, MA. Note: Section B – Weak Squares, pp. 69–164.

Comment: Could you pls provide not links but at least titles of the book you are referring to ? Thank you. (I don't see any Seirawan+Silman book from 2020, for instance, after a web search.)

Comment: @Olorin Did you look at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: @Olorin book titles have always been in the answer, including the page numbers for the sections.

Comment: @Olórin I've added screenshots of the book covers.

Comment: Oh thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

Bangiev.

In case that wasn't a sufficient answer: Bangiev has invented
his own training method, book e.g. [here](https://www.amazon.de/Felderstrategie-Denkmethode-Alexander-Bangiev/dp/3939345067) (no idea of an English
version exists - he is a German trainer), which heavily relies
on weak color complexes. Be warned that the method is disputed,
to say the least (that even stands in the Wiki, which says
something).
Evidently already Nimzowitsch knew one or the other thing, as
shown in this (also German, sorry) [Google book search excerpt](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Schachstrategie_f%C3%BCr_Vereinsspieler/T9YlDAAAQBAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=schach%20schwache%20farbkomplexe&pg=PA150&printsec=frontcover) which has a chapter on the theme.
[English book which has this as *one* theme.](https://www.schachversand.de/improve-your-positional-chess.html)